# Elasticsearch slow search query

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Elasticsearch is taking long time to return records. I have total around 40000 records in the index. Previously I was using Mysql db which was taking around 30 seconds to return data then I moved to Elasticsearch for improving the search experience but Elasticssearch is also taking around 25 seconds.
here is my query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "from_name_field_subject_content": "ups"
        }
      },
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "from_name": "ups"
          }
        }
      ],
      "boost": 1
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 100
}
```

**mapping**

```
{
  "mapping": {
    "properties": {
      "bcc_field": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "cc_field": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "con_us_id": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "created_by": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "created_by_group": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "created_on": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "ema_con_log_id": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "ema_rea_by_id": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "ema_ref_num_id": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "email_imap_unique_id": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "email_opened": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "email_opened_date": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "forward_from_email_id": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "from_field": {
        "type": "text",
        "copy_to": [
          "from_name_field_subject_content"
        ]
      },
      "from_name": {
        "type": "text",
        "copy_to": [
          "from_name_field_subject_content"
        ]
      },
      "from_name_field_subject_content": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "full_content": {
        "type": "text",
        "copy_to": [
          "from_name_field_subject_content"
        ]
      },
      "in_reply_to": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "is_active": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "is_archived": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "is_delete": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "is_draft": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "is_flagged": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "is_invoice": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "is_junk": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "is_read": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "is_spam": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "recent_content": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "subject_field": {
        "type": "text",
        "copy_to": [
          "from_name_field_subject_content"
        ]
      },
      "to_field": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "updated_on": {
        "type": "date"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*full_content* is the field which contain a long text data (whole email content with html init)

Comment: I do see some red flags like having lot of mapping, using `must` etc. I have faced the same and documented some tips here: https://shahsmit.hashnode.dev/elastic-search-tips-and-tricks-for-beginners hope it helps!

Comment: I think you need to do something to decrease the unique number of terms of the from_name_field_subject_content field.